Is Intel TBB concurrent vector of doubles lock-free?
I am writing C++ multithreaded code using GCC C++20 on Intel Broadwell XEONs or AMD EPYC 7551s, Intel TBB, and Pagmo2 libraries for optimization problems. If I declare concurrent_vector<double> X and the elements of X are concurrently modified by multiple running threads, I believe the operations would be thread-safe. Please kindly correct me if I'm wrong.
My real question is this: If multiple threads access the elements of X, i.e. more than one thread attempts to simultaneously modify an element of X, e.g. X.at(5), will the operation be atomic and lock-free or will there be a lock with significant performance consequences? Also, let's say that thread 0 modifies X.at(i) while thread 1 simultaneously modifies X.at(j) with i != j. What will be the performance implications and will the operation be lock-free i.e. atomic?
I am new to concurrent C++/TBB and was not able to find a definitive, clear answer using a Google search.
I have searched Google and the TBB documentation but have not found a clear answer to the above question yet. I'm not sure if TBB concurrent containers are actually atomic?

If you look at the API, at(i) just returns a reference to the contained value. Concurrent modification of the value at i by multiple threads would be the same as with a regular std::vector and be undefined behavior under C++ rules, unless the data type itself allows atomic modifications.

As far as I can tell, the only feature of this class is concurrent growth. There is nothing about locking elements. And since elements are not moved when the vector grows, there is no need to lock them for access, anyway.

@Homer512 it is a bit subtle. The at(i) synchronizes with growth (according to the link you send) and then returns a reference. And then "if and only if" the vector does not resize you can use the reference. That reference itself is then only as threadsafe as the referenced type.  All in all still not a good datatype for concurrent access under resize conditions. So I would probably use a std::vector + std::mutex to be sure ... I don't know about any lock free implementations of vector.

@OP maybe you need to be a bit more explicit about what you expect from your datastructure. What kind of read/write/grow behavior do you expect. Because it may well be a vector like datastructure is not the one you need (you explain your question in terms of "HOW" not "WHAT")

@PepijnKramer You sure about that? When I read can be performed concurrently with each other, concurrent growth methods […], I assume the reference stays valid while another thread grows the vector. Otherwise this would be very misleading. And it doesn't seem to synchronize as such, since it they write In case of concurrent growth, the element returned by the access method can refer to the element that is under construction of the other thread.. So if you access an element that was appended by another thread, the element may have been allocated but not constructed

A solution might be to access vector elements through atomic references. But note that architectures typically do not support atomic memory operations with floating-point data types. Any attempt to do so usually results in a lot of machine code containing moves between registers and a loop around compare-exchange atomics (demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8sq1P8jr8), which is generally pretty slow. In some situations (such as matrix-vector multiplication), it is better to provide each thread with its own output vector and reduce them at the end.

@PepijnKramer I just checked the source code and I don't see any locks or other measures in the element access code path. The underlying data structure is an array of of arrays which are vector segments of exponentially growing size. Access is atomic and lock-free, just 3 acquire loads (size, table, segment) until it returns the reference

@Homer512 No I am not sure, that's how I interpret the documentation (I didn't check the implementation).

From looking at the code, it seems pretty clear to me that the entire point of this structure is to have fast, lock-free vector.push_back() (and friends) for things like capturing unordered lists of results where the number is not known a-priori. Like unordered, parallelized std::copy_if and similar

@Homer512 I agree, the documentation says that growing does not invalidate references to existing elements. Calling this container "vector" is quite misleading, since vectors are contiguous containers, while this one is not.

@Homer512: So, for thread-safe atomic access to an existing element, I guess you'd want to use std::atomic_ref<double>.

@PeterCordes Yes, but if you access an element created by another thread, you have to manually insert some synchronization. For example push_back increments the size before initializing the value.

Thanks for all your ideas! I forgot to mention that my plan, if concurrent access to elements of tbb::concurrent_vector were lock-free and threadsafe, was that I would hold the vector's size constant while threads were accessing and modifying its elements. All the memory allocation and sizing would be done just once in the program, in a single thread, at the beginning. My question was, would this be thread-safe and lock free? Thanks again.

If the size does not change concurrently, this is the wrong structure. Use a regular vector of doubles and then use std::atomic_ref to access the elements. Or if you can't use C++20, use std::unique_ptr<std::atomic<double>[]>. However, don't underestimate the overhead of having multiple threads writing to the same value. I highly recommend that you structure your code so that each thread works on its own values with no interference for as long as possible

Hi Homer512, Thanks for your suggestions. While my first iteration of my code will likely avoid concurrent modifications of the vector array, I might want to eventually try my algorithm using the concurrent modification. Hopefully, it turns out to be truly atomic, lock-free, and efficient? However, even if it's "lock free" I'm imagining that having a swarm of threads contending for access to each of the vector elements could still slow things down. Moreover in my algorithm, it might make sense to allocate separate vectors for NUMA. Thanks for instructing me on C++ atomic_ref! Phil

Okay. For future reference, please write @Homer512 (or whoever you want to respond to). That way we get a notification for your comment. Only the one writing the question (or answer for comments to that answer) gets a notification automatically

...will the operation be lock-free i.e. atomic?
There will be no locks, but that does not mean it behaves like std::atomic

concurrent_vector allows multiple threads to access (read, write, take
the address) of the same element. It does not serialize the accesses,
so whether those accesses are safe depends upon the data type.

What will be the performance implications ...

tbb::concurrent_vector deals with the problem by not moving existing
storage when resizing. Instead, in order to grow, it creates a new
chunk of storage. The chunks are accessed by a fast constant-time
indexing scheme. See tbb/concurrent_vector.h for how it is
implemented.
However, there is no free lunch here. The concurrent_vector indexing
introduces an extra level of complexity compared to std::vector. So if
you do not need to concurrently grow and access a vector, I recommend
using std::vector. But if you do have multiple threads appending to a
dynamically growing array, then concurrent_vector can be a good fit.

The performance cost to access an element is non-negligible due to the implementation, which is required to support the use case of concurrently growing & accessing a vector.

Note: Quotes are taken from https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Threading-Building/concurrent-vector-thread-safety/m-p/912060 for an answer from a likely Intel employee (since their username contains _INTEL).
